# How to change color in git diff

Tags: git, git-diff

I was able to change color for `old`, `new`, and `meta` regions, but I can't find the option to change the color of `@@ -1 +1, 2 @@` (in the picture) and the color of the red square at the end (in the picture).

[image: git diff output]

Comment: does the whitespace color work for you? on my machine it doesn't... :/

Comment: Yes, I need to set background color for whitespace.

Comment: whitespace = white white

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hunk header color option is called `color.diff.frag`.

Whitespace at the end is called `color.diff.whitespace`.
Whitespace uses background color so you have to set both colors (thanks @IGRACH)

You can test it like this:

`git -c color.diff.frag=yellow -c color.diff.whitespace='cyan cyan' diff`

For completeness, the rest of options are:

- context (context text - plain is a historical synonym)
- meta (metainformation)
- frag (hunk header)
- func (function in hunk header)
- old (removed lines)
- new (added lines)
- commit (commit headers)
- whitespace (highlighting whitespace errors)
- oldMoved (deleted lines)
- newMoved (added lines)
- oldMovedDimmed
- oldMovedAlternative
- oldMovedAlternativeDimmed
- newMovedDimmed
- newMovedAlternative
- newMovedAlternativeDimmed
- contextDimmed
- oldDimmed
- newDimmed
- contextBold
- oldBold
- newBold

Available colors: *normal, black, red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, white and default*

Comment: I appears that I can't change color for whitespace, because it uses background color.